# 3 Level propensity score matching SAS

Tags: sas

In my study I've 3 levels, 2 treatment and 1 control effect.  I want to do propensity score matching at 3 level. Could anyone please guide me how to proceed doing PSM. Also, if there's any literature I can refer to.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @StuSztukowski: I tried "twang" for SAS (required to install R package, which I can't do) and %GI macro (need IML which I don't have in my SAS licence). The issue I'm having because of infrastructure restrictions, I can't use above 2 options. So wondering if there are some other options other than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just to clarify, you've got a treatment variable that can take 3 values (treatment A, treatment B and control), and you want a process that (1) assigns a probability that an indivdual unit of study (subject, school, whatever) has to be in one of the treatment groups, and (2) makes triads with one unit from treatment A, one from treatment B and one from control that are of similar probabilities?

I think most of the people who can help you with this question think of multilevel/heirarchical data (like for instance, patients nested within doctors nested within clinics) when they hear 'matching at 3 levels', which doesn't seem like what you're trying to do.

Anyway, assuming that I've read you right, the general approach that I'd take is to use proc logistic (or proc glimmix maybe for hierarchical data) to find the propensity, or predicted probability if you'd rather, of being in treatment A, and then use something like the [%gmatch macro](http://www.mayo.edu/research/departments-divisions/department-health-sciences-research/division-biomedical-statistics-informatics/software/locally-written-sas-macros) to match treatment A 1:1 with controls. Then run your matching algortihm again to match treatment A with treatment B. Merge your matched sets together on treatment A id # and there you have it. Naturally, there are a lot of smaller subparts of all of this would take hours to go through in sufficient detail; I propose asking about those as separate, smaller and most importantly more specific questions if you're having trouble with any of them.

Here's a paper that I found helpful when I was first learning about propensity scores:
http://www.stat.ubc.ca/~john/papers/DAgostinoSIM1998.pdf

This might be of some use as well:
http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi25/25/po/25p225.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You got it right. I'm exactly doing the thing you have written. But I don't want it to be hierarchical. Suppose I've 2 fertilizers and want to test which fertilizer is better than other compared to not using any treatment to the soil. It seems I've to follow the same suggestions that you gave of comparing 2 groups at a time rather than 3 groups together in case don't get any better suggestions.

Comment: Great, glad that helped, but one thing - you can do 3 groups this way, it's just matching two groups at a time. Once you have your matched controls and matched fertilizer B's for every id number of fertilizer A, join the two datasets together on id number and you have your propensity matched triplets.  Then do some sort of analysis (usually another logistic regression) that conditions on the triplet. BTW, you can also match on multiple factors with %gmatch, so you could make two separate propensity scores for fertilizer A and fertilizer B, and match on both of these, if that is important.